# Is it ok to split a transformer directly off the wiring from an outlet junction

Tags: transformer, splicing

I am installing a doorbell transformer for a new Ring doorbell and I have an outlet right next to the main box. It would be simple for me to take the existing wiring, branch it and use it for the new transformer (which I could attach to the side of this junction). That would save me from having to run any more wire - simply take the wiring provided as part of the transformer and splice it to the existing run. Is there any reason that this is not a valid setup before I go about doing it?

[image]

Comment: There are transformers that can attach directly to the knock out in the side of your box - is that what you're talking about?  Side note, that exposed romex/NM cable isn't to code.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes - and what exposed romex?

Comment: The white wire coming out of the top of that disassembled box.  Unless it's behind a finished wall (it's not because we can see it), it should be in conduit.  Not a huge deal, but it's a sign to watch out for other work that might not be exactly up to code.

Comment: Ahh, yah. No, this is all behind an access panel. The plug in this case is there merely for a septic tank alert system. Otherwise this is all enclosed. Thanks for the note of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine, it looks like that's just a general purpose receptacle and it's OK to add a small load like a doorbell transformer to that circuit.  It looks like there's room in the box, and clearance so the transformer will fit.

Comment: Might be easier to use a plug in style, like a PWS-1640, $15 on Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine.  Fit it in the open/missing knockout hole, that way you don't have to plug that hole.